# What does this HTTP header mean? OpenCart (PHP) code

Tags: php, http-headers, opencart

What does this HTTP header mean?

```
if (!defined('DIR_APPLICATION')) { 
    header('Location: install/index.php'); 
    exit; 
}
```

It is part of OpenCart (PHP) code.

Is DIR_APPLICATION a constant or a directory?
What does header mean in that context?

After reading [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP) and [W3C](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), I still can not understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Guessing Open Cart?  It is a constant defined in the applications code.

Comment: @ficuscr: Thanks for your comment. Yes, it is OpenCart. Does that mean that DIR_APPLICATION constant is created inside install/index.php file?

Comment: if not installed, then redirect to the installer.... What doublesharp is saying...

Comment: @ficuscr: Thank you. If OpenCart is not installed, will the user be redirected to install/index.php?

Comment: Looks like understanding of PHP basics is missing here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DIR_APPLICATION` is actually the constant defined to say where the main directory holding the `controller`, `language`, `model` and `view` directories are for the Admin/Catalog sections of the application. It is a full path structure of the local file system to the directory that is written to the `config.php` when the installation is completed. It is defined in each of the two `config.php` files and as such if it isn't defined, OpenCart assumes that there's not been an installation and redirects to the installation script. Not sure why you've referred to it as a header though as it's in no way a header

Comment: :In the code I wrote there's a word "header". Is that a HTTP header? I installed OpenCart and found the two config.php files you mentioned: both have a DIR_APPLICATION constant but the second one has the following value "www.mysite.com/**catalog**". It points to catalog folder. If I enter www.mysite.com/catalog, the browser shows me the four folders inside catalog folder. Are those two DIR_APPLICATIONS constants are created when the following code in /install/index.php is parsed? `define('DIR_APPLICATION', str_replace('\'', '/', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/');`

Comment: Ah, yes that is a HTTP header I guess - it's the redirect to the installer itself but is nothing to do with the `DIR_APPLICATION` constant. Not sure why you'd go to the `/catalog/` folder however. The constant is for the file structure not for the HTTP structure so that files can be found internally by the application. The `DIR_APPLICATION` you refer to above is actually just the location of the files for the installation MVC - the one for OpenCart's `config.php` files is in the file `/install/controller/step_3.php`

Comment: Thank you very much, Jay. You were really helpful. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

`DIR_APPLICATION` is a constant that likely *should* hold the the application's installation directory, if it fails the [`defined()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) check, meaning that it has not been set/defined as part of the installation, it sends HTTP headers to the client using [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) causing a redirect to `install/index.php`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is DIR_APPLICATION constant created as soon as this piece of code is parsed into PHP? And then the user is redirected to install/index.php if OpenCart is not installed?

Comment: thanks for your edited answer. Does that mean that DIR_APPLICATION constant is created after OpenCart is installed?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenCart specifically, but this is common in PHP applications. You usually have a config file that will define certain constants used elsewhere in the app.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am about to understand it fully. So in case DIR_APPLICATION constant does not exist, not only the client will be redirected to install/index.php but also **DIR_APPLICATION will be defined**?

Comment: No, my guess is that install/index.php is a page that will then let you configure the application, included some type of config file. That config file will then define `DIR_APPLICATION` and the next time it's loaded you won't get redirected.